# Get PostgreSql table size on disk (byte) in ORMlite

Tags: java, postgresql, ormlite

I use ORMLite in a Java application, in order to deal with a PostgreSql DataBase.
I want to get the space on the disc used by a table of DataBase.
It seems that OrmLite doesn't have a specific method to get it, so I tried without success:

```
final String TABLE_NAME = "a_table_name_of_db";

//1)
String SQL = "SELECT pg_relation_size('" + TABLE_NAME + "');"  ;
int result = OGGETTO_DAO.executeRaw(SQL); 

//2)
String SQL = "SELECT pg_table_size('" + TABLE_NAME + "');"  ;
int result = OGGETTO_DAO.executeRaw(SQL); 

//3 - it was just a try...)
SQL = "SELECT pg_table_size('" + TABLE_NAME + "');"  ;
GenericRawResults<String> ARRAY = OGGETTO_DAO.queryRaw(SQL);
String result= ARRAY.getFirstResult();
```

With 1) and 2) I get always -1, with 3) I get a cast exception;

I I use the command 'pg_relation_size' or 'pg_table_size' by command line (linux - by psql prompt), it works properly.

What am I wrong?
Thank you

UPDATE - WORKING SOLUTION:

Now it works! Solution, as per accepted answer below, is:

```
final String TABLE_NAME = "a_table_name_of_db";
String SQL = "SELECT pg_table_size('" + TABLE_NAME  + "');"  
final long RESULT = OGGETTO_DAO.queryRawValue(SQL); //in bytes
```

Comment: @Abra  thanks, I already saw that post, but the problem is that I'm using ORMlite; accoriding to my code, it is quite complicated to use something different from ORMlite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `int result = OGGETTO_DAO.executeRaw(SQL);`

Yeah that's not right.  Looking at the [javadocs for executeRaw(...)](https://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/dao/Dao.html#executeRaw-java.lang.String-java.lang.String...-) they say that it returns the number of rows affected *not* the result.

> SQL = "SELECT pg_table_size('" + TABLE_NAME + "');"  ;
> GenericRawResults ARRAY = OGGETTO_DAO.queryRaw(SQL);
> String result= ARRAY.getFirstResult();

Looking at the [javadocs for `queryRaw(...)`](https://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/dao/Dao.html#queryRaw-java.lang.String-java.lang.String...-), the problem here is it returns a `GenericRawResults<String[]>` and not `<String>`.  It returns a collection of raw results, each row being represented by a string array.  I'm really surprised that your code even compiles.

It should be:

```
GenericRawResults<String[]> ARRAY = OGGETTO_DAO.queryRaw(SQL);
String result= ARRAY.getFirstResult()[0];
```

Probably the best way to do this is to use [`queryRawValue(...)`](https://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/dao/Dao.html#queryRawValue-java.lang.String-java.lang.String...-) which performs a raw query and returns a single value.

```
// throws an exception if there are no results or if the first one isn't a number
long size = OGGETTO_DAO.queryRawValue(SQL);
```

Comment: Yesssss! It works. Aswer accepted. Thank you very much!!!!